# Reset Options Grayed Out in MikTeX Console

Tags: miktex, installing

I need to reinstall MikTeX (as a result of the issues brought up in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572680/updated-packages-now-latex-wont-compile-miktex-configuration-utility-did-n/)), but first I want to clean up/reset my install. However, the reset options in MikTeX Console are grayed out, as is the "Switch to MikTeX aministrator mode" option.

[image: Grayed-Out Cleanup Options]

I'm running a user install on Windows 10 (64-bit). There is no difference if I start MikTeX as administrator from the start menu, and it's like this way on both of the computers (desktop and laptop) I have MikTeX installed on.

My questions are:

- Is this normal?
- If I can't reset my configuration, what kind of horror am I going to visit upon my system if I uninstall and reinstall without doing so?

I did some searching to see if anyone had asked this question before, but I couldn't find an answer: only that you need to reset your MikTeX configuration before uninstalling and some horror stories from failing to do so.

Comment: why don't you simply delete the files in the roaming texmf-tree?

Comment: That's an option for my other question (the answer being: I don't know what files are supposed to be there and which ones are not), but does not answer this question.

Comment: Well you are willing to deinstall and so delete everything. So where is the problem to go first through the folder and delete whatever you consider not to belong there as it is for example also in a newer version in the other tree? I never deinstalled MiKTeX so I don't know the options but if something is grayed out I would assume that it isn't applicable.

Comment: With all due respect, that sounds like a good answer to my last query in the other question. It still does not answer *this* question.